# XML parsing is slow and takes up 90% of processing time inside the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database, query-optimization

I have a stored procedure that takes an xml file as one of the inputs. The XML file contains the region ids. I have to get all the region ids into a temp table and use it in the subsequent queries inside the stored procedure.

Here's the code that parses the xml inside the stored proc:

```
Declare @xml XML = '<regions>
<regionId>7C3BD242-D835-4748-96D7-9C91B6048549</regionId>
<regionId>25B7B2CF-4E0E-4873-B2FB-F3BFCFFB4228</regionId>
</regions>'

Select r.c.value('.','uniqueidentifier')
  Into #region
  From @xml.nodes('/regions/regionId/text()') r(c)
```

This was not performing well and was taking up almost 99% of the query execution time in the query plan. So we added a hint to optimize it.

```
Select r.c.value('.','uniqueidentifier')
  Into #region
  From @xml.nodes('/regions/regionId/text()') r(c)
 OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR (@xml = null))
```

This improved the performance a bit and the query execution time for the xml came down to 85%. The SP executes in about 10 seconds out of which the XML processing takes about 5 seconds.
What I find amusing is why would such a simple query take up so much query cost when the subsequent queries have tables that have millions of rows in them and don't take as much time.

I would really appreciate it if anyone has suggestions on how I can improve the performance.

Note: I tried running the SP with just the select statement for the XML parsing without the temp table and it still took about 85% of the query execution time. We're on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: "the query execution time for the xml came down to 85%" - from the fact that you later say it takes 5 seconds out of 10 this is clearly not the case. (50%) - you are presumably misinterpreting estimated cost pct. This is not a reliable indicator. Especially for plans with XML. e.g. it gives that trivial document in the Q a subtree cost of `2.23181` rather than actually analyse its complexity during optimisation. How big is the actual XML that you are parsing that is taking 5 seconds?

Comment: There's no way that parsing a simple 4-line XML document is going to take 5 seconds - something else is going on here. If something takes such a crazy length of time my first line of investigation would be to look at network traffic: is anything being fetched remotely?

Comment: If it **is** that document then I question your methodology for getting the per statement timing.

Comment: @MartinSmith The maximum number of Ids I see are 50 but on an average there around around 10 region Ids in each call. The one that took me 5 seconds to parse is the one I posted.

Comment: That doesn’t take 5 seconds to parse then. There is something wrong with how you are measuring this or the blockage was with the temp table creation

Comment: @MartinSmith The way I measured this was I ran the stored procedure with XML parsing and it took 10 seconds. The next time, I removed the xml parsing and created a temp table with the two region Ids using insert into #region select '7C3BD242-D835-4748-96D7-9C91B6048549' union select '25B7B2CF-4E0E-4873-B2FB-F3BFCFFB4228' and the procedure ran in 5 seconds.

Comment: This is not at all the correct method. All you likely established was that the actual slow part was faster when you ran it a second time and data was in cache and maybe stats had been auto updated on first run increasing elapsed times. You need to gather actual statement level execution timings not try and infer them like that

Comment: I forgot to mention that I created a separate stored procedure when I did the second part so that they are independent of each other. In that case, no cache would be used, right?

Comment: Not of execution plans but the second run would still benefit from any statistics created during the first run and data pages read from disc into the buffer cache

Comment: It's likely the temp table insert is itself the problem. Why do you need the temp table anyway? Also what happens if you try removing `/text` from the `.nodes` call and put it into `.value('text()[1]','uniqueidentifier')`

Answer (score 2):

> XML parsing is slow and takes up 90% of processing time inside the
> stored procedure

- XML parsing can be problematic in SQL Server - especially when you get an execution plan that [repeatedly re-process the same XML processing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30947/3690) but this isn't the case here.
- No it doesn't take "90% of processing time" - you are reading way too much into the "Query Cost (relative to the batch)" percentages. This is purely a ratio of *estimated* sub tree cost per plan across all plans in the batch (even with actual execution plans)

Take the example below.

```
Declare @xml XML = '<regions>
<regionId>7C3BD242-D835-4748-96D7-9C91B6048549</regionId>
<regionId>25B7B2CF-4E0E-4873-B2FB-F3BFCFFB4228</regionId>
</regions>'

Select r.c.value('.','uniqueidentifier') as x
From @xml.nodes('/regions/regionId/text()') r(c)
OPTION(LOOP JOIN)

Select r.c.value('.','uniqueidentifier')
From @xml.nodes('/regions/regionId/text()') r(c)
OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR (@xml = null))
```

[image]

Both execution plans are identical. It is absolutely not the case that the addition of the `OPTIMIZE FOR (@xml = null)` hint improved anything at runtime to warrant the 97% vs 3% cost percentages shown.

All that happened was that it changed the *estimated* number of rows going into the nested loops join from `66` to `1` so changed the expected number of executions of the inner side accordingly. In reality the number of rows and corresponding executions is `2` in both cases.

The costings of the XML operators themselves are way overstated in this case. The optimiser has no idea what the contents of the `@xml` variable will be and the costs for these operators are the same regardless of the size of document you actually assign to the variable.

Your methodology for gathering statement level execution durations is flawed. If you are running this in SSMS then the easiest way in SQL Server 2012 would probably be to run `SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;` first (you may find adding `PRINT` statements inside the proc useful to quickly associate the output with a statement).

You can also look in `dm_exec_query_stats` to get historic information about timings per statement as long as the execution plan is in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Often (in my experience at least) XML can be pretty slow.

As an alternative maybe consider treating the xml as just a string and apply *string_split* to extract the values - something like:

```
Declare @xml varchar(max) = '<regions>
<regionId>7C3BD242-D835-4748-96D7-9C91B6048549</regionId>
<regionId>25B7B2CF-4E0E-4873-B2FB-F3BFCFFB4228</regionId>
</regions>'

select [value] into #region
from (select Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(@xml,Char(13)+Char(10),''),'<regionId>',''),'<regions>',''),'</regions>',''),'</regionId>',','))x(x)
cross apply String_Split(x, ',')
where value !=''
```

Comment: This is a great solution but unfortunately we're still on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: That's unfortunate, there are so many improvements available in newer versions - it's really time you upgraded, you may even find the xml parsing is improved in the latest version.